# Formal semantics of subordinate clauses (compound sentences) - in categorial and type logical grammars?

Tags: syntax, grammar, formal-semantics, subordination, montague-grammar

I am trying to apply combinatory categorial grammars and type logical grammars (Montague semantics etc.) to the compound sentences and the subordinate clauses. Are there efforts to  develop those grammars for such analysis? E.g. there is syntactic category s (sentence), are there syntactic categories for subordinate clauses? Does the type logical semantics of subordinate clause is just elaboration (additional constraint) on some word in the main sentence to which the subordinate clause refers? Are there examples in the literature of such analysis?

Google gives no good references, good reference can be the answer, I can read it myself further.

E.g. how to analyse sentence:

```
building land — land parcel, 
in relation to which 
a construction permit has been issued for the building thereof 
or 
for the construction of engineering communications therein
```

Answer (score 1):

As I recall (I haven't gone back to McCawley's books to check this), McCawley treats subordinate clauses like prepositional phrases whose objects are sentences, and prepositions as predicates with objects of prepositions as arguments.  I guess that would construe subordinate clauses to be predicates (prepositions) with subordinated clauses (objects of prepositions) and main clauses as arguments and sentences containing subordinate clauses as the results of those predications.

This of course doesn't tell you anything interesting, but I don't think type logical treatments ever do.